# Can't Click on button in tableView cell after reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have in cell implement 3 buttons and button action. After call tableView.reloadData() can't click to any button in cell.

In controller in func cellForRow call cell?.onbuttonTappedAdd and other. Afer add element I call tabelViewReloadData.

//TableViewCell

```
var onButtonTappedAdd : (() -> Void)? = nil
var onButtonTappedRemove : (() -> Void)? = nil


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


func configureCell(orderitem: OrderItem){
    self.orderItem = orderitem!


}

func setButtonGradient(){


}
@IBAction func changeValue(_ sender: Any) {


}

@IBAction func btnAddValue(_ sender: Any) {
    if let onButtonTappedAdd = self.onButtonTappedAdd
    {
    onButtonTappedAdd()
    }
}
@IBAction func btnRemoveValue(_ sender: Any) {
    if let onButtonTappedRemove = self.onButtonTappedRemove {
    onButtonTappedRemove()
    }
}
```

//ViewControll cellForRow

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   var cell = tableViewOrderItem.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderItemCheckoutCell", for: indexPath)
        as? OrderItemCheckoutCell
    var orderItem = GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row]

    cell?.configureCell(orderitem: orderItem)

   cell?.onButtonTappedAdd = {

              GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].quantity = GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].quantity! + (GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].Product?.bigValue)!

   self.tableViewOrderItem.reloadData()

     self.setTotalInfo()
    }
    cell?.onButtonTappedRemove = {

                 GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].quantity = GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].quantity! - (GlobalArray.orderArrayList[indexPath.section].ListOrderItem[indexPath.row].Product?.bigValue)!
                       self.tableViewOrderItem.reloadData()
        }


    return cell!

}
```

Comment: Post the code for your `cellForRow(at:)` method

Comment: @DuncanC
I tried but after 3 times the same problem

Comment: attach the code of **cellForRowAt** in the question

Comment: "I tried but after 3 times the same problem". Huh? Edit your question and add the code for your  cellForRow(at:) method so we can see what it does.

Comment: @DuncanC sorry ... I am update question

Comment: "After call tableView.reloadData() can't click to any button in cell." What does that mean? What happens when you tap on cells?

Comment: @DuncanC after "self.tableViewOrderItem.reloadData()" I can't click on any button in cell. Nothing, the same as the blocked cell

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the code of your button closures and see if it breaks when you tap your buttons.

Comment: Just an opinion you could easily make use of protocol for this

Answer (score 0):

Reload TableView Outside of the "cellforRow" method